# Unable to download map data from OpenStreetMap

Tags: android, jar, openstreetmap, http-status-code-403

While executing

```
`java -jar OSMMapTilePackager-6.1.1-SNAPSHOT.jar -u http://b.tile.openstreetmap.org/%d/%d/%d.png -t Mapnik -d at_mapnik_13.zip -zmax 15 -n 49.03942 -s 46.40162 -e 17.14736 -w 9.44595`
```

I get 403 (Forbidden access), but when I execute it in the browser, I get a tile as an image file.

Is there something related to the policy that I have missed. I am trying to download map files and use them for offline use.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your question should read "unable to download map tiles from OpenStreetMap", as you're not loading (raw) map data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bulk downloads are usually forbidden. See the [tile usage policy](https://operations.osmfoundation.org/policies/tiles/). Quoting the important parts:

> OpenStreetMap’s own servers are run entirely on donated resources.
>
> OpenStreetMap data is free for everyone to use. Our tile servers are not.
>
> Bulk downloading is strongly discouraged. Do not download tiles unnecessarily.
> In particular, downloading significant areas of tiles at zoom levels 17 and higher for offline or later usage is forbidden [...]

You can [render](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Rendering) your own *raster* tiles by installing a rendering software such as [TileMill](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/TileMill) or by [installing your own tile-server](https://switch2osm.org/). Alternatively take a look at [Commercial OSM software and services](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Commercial_OSM_Software_and_Services).

Alternatively switch to [*vector* tiles](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Vector_tiles). Obtaining raw OSM data is rather easy. Vector tiles allow you to render tiles on your device on the fly.